# WPF ListView - 2 dimensions with 1 same structure

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, binding

We are working on a ListView (C# WPF) and we didn't found how bind a list of items in columns, with each item containing itself a list of items with the same columns.

Let's illustre this in an example :

[image: Exemple of our objective]
!

We got an observable collection on objects with parameters (name, etc.) and each object contain another observable collection of objects with the sames parameters (exept they haven't a list). So we want to list it in a ListView but we can't figure how !

We do not know enough ListView to implement this structure, some advices ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's not an exactly straightforward thing to do. you want your group items to be re-sizable too?

Comment: They got the sames columns (sames parameters) so i want to have only 1 ListView. Do you think it is possible ?

Comment: You can get your grouping without resizable group level items just by uing CollectionViewSource with GroupDescriptions, just check MSDN for those. If you want your group level items to behave similarly to the ungrouped items, it adds up a whole lot of complexity to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is :

XAML :

```
<Window.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="gridViewSecondCellTemplate1">
            <StackPanel Width="100">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" FontSize="15" />
            </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="gridViewCellTemplate1">
            <StackPanel Width="100">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MySecondSource}>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Subtitle}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource gridViewSecondCellTemplate1}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Col 1" Width="100" CellTemplate="{StaticResource gridViewCellTemplate1}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

I didn't try this code. Try it, and say me if it is OK.